# could not synchronize on CUDA context: CUDA_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: Tensorflow-gpu working very slowly on RTX 2070super

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, parallel-processing, gpu

Short Version:
I have written an genetic algorithm with keras where each model in one epoch gets the same inputs and prodduces different outputs which I can validate. For what ever reason tensorflow uses my gpu but only with 1% performance (but at least it uses all the RAM). This process is only twice as fast as my cpu. So I wanted to use multiprocessing to at least train 100 Models at the same time. But CUDA seams to have a problem with that.

The Error code:

```
2020-09-29 09:23:45.040414: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:951] could not synchronize on CUDA context: CUDA_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: initialization error :: *** Begin stack trace ***
        tensorflow::CurrentStackTrace()
        stream_executor::gpu::GpuDriver::SynchronizeContext(stream_executor::gpu::GpuContext*)
        stream_executor::StreamExecutor::SynchronizeAllActivity()
        tensorflow::GPUUtil::SyncAll(tensorflow::Device*)
        tensorflow::BaseGPUDevice::Sync()
        tensorflow::TensorHandle::CopyToDevice(tensorflow::EagerContext const&, tensorflow::Device*, tensorflow::Tensor*)
        tensorflow::TensorHandle::Resolve(tensorflow::Status*)
        TFE_TensorHandleResolve






        _PyFunction_Vectorcall


        _PyFunction_Vectorcall


        _PyFunction_Vectorcall


        _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName
        _PyFunction_Vectorcall
        _PyObject_FastCallDict
        _PyObject_Call_Prepend

        _PyObject_MakeTpCall

        _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName
        _PyFunction_Vectorcall
        PyVectorcall_Call
        _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
        _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName



        _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName
        _PyFunction_Vectorcall


        _PyFunction_Vectorcall
        PyVectorcall_Call
        _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
        _PyFunction_Vectorcall
        PyVectorcall_Call
        _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
        _PyFunction_Vectorcall


        _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName



        _PyFunction_Vectorcall


        _PyObject_FastCallDict
        _PyObject_Call_Prepend

        _PyObject_MakeTpCall

        _PyFunction_Vectorcall


        _PyFunction_Vectorcall


        _PyFunction_Vectorcall


        _PyFunction_Vectorcall


        _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName
        _PyFunction_Vectorcall


        _PyFunction_Vectorcall


        _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName
        PyEval_EvalCodeEx
        PyEval_EvalCode




        _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName
        _PyFunction_Vectorcall


        _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName
        _PyFunction_Vectorcall


        _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName
        _PyFunction_Vectorcall


        _PyFunction_Vectorcall

        _PyFunction_Vectorcall

        _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName
        PyEval_EvalCodeEx
        PyEval_EvalCode



        _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName
        _PyFunction_Vectorcall

        _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName
        _PyFunction_Vectorcall
        PyVectorcall_Call


        Py_BytesMain
        __libc_start_main

*** End stack trace ***
```

Long Version:
Thanks for reading by the way.
Like I said I am writing a genetic algorithm with Tensorflow. I have for example 5 epochs, in each epoch are 10 models with 1000 timesteps to train them on. The problem ist that after every timestep (every time i feed something through the Model) I am using that output of the model to run some code that has influence of the input of the next timestep. So my code looks something like this:

```
for e in range(len(epochs)):
  for m in range(len(models)):
    for t in range(len(timesteps)):

      output = current_pool[m].predict(x=neural_input, batch_size=1)

      do_something(output)
```

I installed Tensorflow-GPU and ran this test and see if the gpu is actually in use:

```
print("GPU Available: ", tf.test.is_gpu_available())
```

The output was:

```
    2020-09-29 10:29:34.023544: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2020-09-29 10:29:34.048725: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:104] CPU Frequency: 3392090000 Hz
2020-09-29 10:29:34.049098: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x55d402523970 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-09-29 10:29:34.049123: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-09-29 10:29:34.051904: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2020-09-29 10:29:34.158278: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-09-29 10:29:34.158838: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x55d4025bef00 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-09-29 10:29:34.158855: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER, Compute Capability 7.5
2020-09-29 10:29:34.159028: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-09-29 10:29:34.159447: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.77GHz coreCount: 40 deviceMemorySize: 7.79GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2020-09-29 10:29:34.159484: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-09-29 10:29:34.160743: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-09-29 10:29:34.161988: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-09-29 10:29:34.162231: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-09-29 10:29:34.163486: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-09-29 10:29:34.164267: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-09-29 10:29:34.167046: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-09-29 10:29:34.167242: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-09-29 10:29:34.167759: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-09-29 10:29:34.168171: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-09-29 10:29:34.168225: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-09-29 10:29:34.522348: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1257] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-09-29 10:29:34.522386: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1263]      0 
2020-09-29 10:29:34.522393: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1276] 0:   N 
2020-09-29 10:29:34.522607: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-09-29 10:29:34.523069: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-09-29 10:29:34.523476: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1402] Created TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0 with 7267 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
GPU Available:  True
```

So my gpu is in use, good.
Now my first problem is that my gpu (RTX 2070super) is extreamly slow. It uses not even 1% of the power. My old gpu GTX 770 was like 10 times faster with basicly the same code. (I have to say that to get the GTX 770 to run with tensorflow-gpu support was quite the calange because of the compute capability of the gtx 770. I used a pre-built tensorflow wheel from GitHub that supported 3.0)

With my  RTX 2070super I am using the conda tensorflow-gpu envirement on my linux server that holds the gpu. And I am connected via ssh from my Windows pc to the envirement on my linux server Version 18.04. But that the GPU is located on a linux server shouldn't be a problem, or could it?

I can list everything that is installed in that tensorflow-gpu envirement down below:

```
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main
_tflow_select             2.1.0                       gpu
absl-py                   0.10.0                   py38_0
astunparse                1.6.3                      py_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
blinker                   1.4                      py38_0
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py38h7b6447c_1000
c-ares                    1.16.1               h7b6447c_0
ca-certificates           2020.7.22                     0
cachetools                4.1.1                      py_0
certifi                   2020.6.20                py38_0
cffi                      1.14.3           py38he30daa8_0
chardet                   3.0.4                 py38_1003
click                     7.1.2                      py_0
cryptography              3.1              py38h1ba5d50_0
cudatoolkit               10.1.243             h6bb024c_0
cudnn                     7.6.5                cuda10.1_0
cupti                     10.1.168                      0
cycler                    0.10.0                   py38_0
dbus                      1.13.16              hb2f20db_0
expat                     2.2.9                he6710b0_2
fontconfig                2.13.0               h9420a91_0
freetype                  2.10.2               h5ab3b9f_0
gast                      0.3.3                      py_0
glib                      2.65.0               h3eb4bd4_0
google-auth               1.21.2                     py_0
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.1                      py_2
google-pasta              0.2.0                      py_0
grpcio                    1.31.0           py38hf8bcb03_0
gst-plugins-base          1.14.0               hbbd80ab_1
gstreamer                 1.14.0               hb31296c_0
h5py                      2.10.0           py38hd6299e0_1
hdf5                      1.10.6               hb1b8bf9_0
icu                       58.2                 he6710b0_3
idna                      2.10                       py_0
importlib-metadata        1.7.0                    py38_0
intel-openmp              2020.2                      254
jpeg                      9b                   h024ee3a_2
keras                     2.4.3                         0
keras-base                2.4.3                      py_0
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                      py_1
kiwisolver                1.2.0            py38hfd86e86_0
lcms2                     2.11                 h396b838_0
ld_impl_linux-64          2.33.1               h53a641e_7
libedit                   3.1.20191231         h14c3975_1
libffi                    3.3                  he6710b0_2
libgcc-ng                 9.1.0                hdf63c60_0
libgfortran-ng            7.3.0                hdf63c60_0
libpng                    1.6.37               hbc83047_0
libprotobuf               3.12.4               hd408876_0
libstdcxx-ng              9.1.0                hdf63c60_0
libtiff                   4.1.0                h2733197_1
libuuid                   1.0.3                h1bed415_2
libxcb                    1.14                 h7b6447c_0
libxml2                   2.9.10               he19cac6_1
lz4-c                     1.9.2                he6710b0_1
markdown                  3.2.2                    py38_0
matplotlib                3.3.1                         0
matplotlib-base           3.3.1            py38h817c723_0
mkl                       2020.2                      256
mkl-service               2.3.0            py38he904b0f_0
mkl_fft                   1.2.0            py38h23d657b_0
mkl_random                1.1.1            py38h0573a6f_0
ncurses                   6.2                  he6710b0_1
numpy                     1.19.1           py38hbc911f0_0
numpy-base                1.19.1           py38hfa32c7d_0
oauthlib                  3.1.0                      py_0
olefile                   0.46                       py_0
openssl                   1.1.1h               h7b6447c_0
opt_einsum                3.1.0                      py_0
pandas                    1.1.1            py38he6710b0_0
pcre                      8.44                 he6710b0_0
pillow                    7.2.0            py38hb39fc2d_0
pip                       20.2.2                   py38_0
protobuf                  3.12.4           py38he6710b0_0
pyasn1                    0.4.8                      py_0
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                      py_0
pycparser                 2.20                       py_2
pyjwt                     1.7.1                    py38_0
pyopenssl                 19.1.0                     py_1
pyparsing                 2.4.7                      py_0
pyqt                      5.9.2            py38h05f1152_4
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py38_0
python                    3.8.5                h7579374_1
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0
pytz                      2020.1                     py_0
pyyaml                    5.3.1            py38h7b6447c_1
qt                        5.9.7                h5867ecd_1
readline                  8.0                  h7b6447c_0
requests                  2.24.0                     py_0
requests-oauthlib         1.3.0                      py_0
rsa                       4.6                        py_0
scipy                     1.5.2            py38h0b6359f_0
setuptools                49.6.0                   py38_0
sip                       4.19.13          py38he6710b0_0
six                       1.15.0                     py_0
sqlite                    3.33.0               h62c20be_0
tensorboard               2.2.1              pyh532a8cf_0
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.6.0                      py_0
tensorflow                2.2.0           gpu_py38hb782248_0
tensorflow-base           2.2.0           gpu_py38h83e3d50_0
tensorflow-estimator      2.2.0              pyh208ff02_0
tensorflow-gpu            2.2.0                h0d30ee6_0
termcolor                 1.1.0                    py38_1
tk                        8.6.10               hbc83047_0
tornado                   6.0.4            py38h7b6447c_1
urllib3                   1.25.10                    py_0
werkzeug                  1.0.1                      py_0
wheel                     0.35.1                     py_0
wrapt                     1.12.1           py38h7b6447c_1
xz                        5.2.5                h7b6447c_0
yaml                      0.2.5                h7b6447c_0
zipp                      3.1.0                      py_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h7b6447c_3
zstd                      1.4.5                h9ceee32_0
```

So to come to a conclusion i have two questions:

1. Why is my gpu so slow when i have tensorflow-gpu installed and tensorflow is using my gpu but my Nvidia GTX 770 is like 10 times faster than the more powerfull RTX 2070super
2. why can't I use multiprocessing to Process multiple Models simultaneously even though the models in one epoch can be trained totaly independently.

Thank you for your time and I hope you have some ideas to help me. :)
If you need more informations about my system let me know.